# AWS DynamoDB queries using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using swift and AWS DynamoDB for mobile app. I followed the tutorial and can save data successfully. However , when I try to load data , i found I the saving and loading data always come after all tasks in the viewdidload finished,  so I can not pass the data out in the same view? Is there any way to save or retire data immediately ?

below is my code

```
mapper.query(Table.self, expression: queryExpress).continueWith{(task: AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
        print("test")
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print("The requst failed. Error: \(error)")
        }
        if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
            for item in paginatedOutput.items
            {
                print("quring")
               //pass info out to array
            }

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching data from the network is an asynchronous action. You can't delay loading the screen while it completes. It may take a long time. It might not ever complete.

Your view controller must handle the case that it doesn't have data yet, and update itself when that data becomes available. The first step to this is avoiding making network queries in your view controller. View controllers should never directly query the network. They should query model objects that outlive the view controller. The model objects are responsible for making queries to the network and updating themselves with the results. Then the view controller will update itself based on the model. The name for this pattern is Model View Controller and is fundamental to Cocoa development. (Search around for many tutorials and discussions of this pattern.)

But regardless of where you make the queries and store the data, you will always have to deal with the case where the data is not yet available, and display something in the meantime. Nothing can fix this in a distributed system.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand you. Do you mean fetching data from network is impossible to return immediately ? And I should fetch them first and put them in the local database such as core data ? And this is not for data unavailable , it's the fetching data does not run until everything has been done .

Comment: "Do you mean fetching data from network is impossible to return immediately?" Exactly. It takes time to query the network. Sometimes quite a lot of time. You can't block the UI while you wait for that (literally; the OS will kill your app if it takes too long). "And I should fetch them first and put them in the local database such as core data ?" Maybe Core Data. Maybe store it in memory. Maybe SQLite, or even flat files. That part isn't really relevant. You can store (or not store) it anyway you want.

Comment: Thank you so much , one more question, if i want to load table on first view of my app , where should I fetch the data ?

Comment: The data should come from your model layer. The model layer will begin its life empty, and add data once it connects to the network. Your view controllers should just show what is in the model layer (so again, they'll start life empty, and then add data when it is available).

Comment: so the model layer is same with core data ?

Comment: Core Data is an implementation of a model layer.

Comment: I searched the Model View Controller , and figured it out. Still thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

When the query finishes successful, load the data into your view. You can send the query in your `viewDidLoad` method, but you need to present the data when it arrives using another method you call when the data did arrive.

Comment: but , my problem is query will not run after all statement finished in the viewdidload , any solution for this case ? Thanks

Comment: This is the solution for your case, make a new method called `processItem(items)` in your view controller and call it like this `processItem(paginatedOutput.items)` from before your `for` statement. In the method `processItem(items)` display your item to the user.

Comment: It's not only the for statement , actually the whole mapper.query block run after all statement in viewDidLoad finished , I really don't know why

Comment: This is how it should work, the "hole statement" is code that will be executed when the query finishes. This is way it is called `continueWith`, continue with {} when query finishes.

Comment: I mean the statements in viewdidload run first , and query go after

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is how it should be, to not block the UI, this is no bug. The query takes some time to run, it is not local. This is why the code executes later.

Comment: `apper.query(Table.self, expression: queryExpress)` this loads the data, and when the data is there `.continueWith {}` (simplified) is executed. in `{}` you set the data in the view.